Is there an R method for identifying ridge lines in a mountain range?
I am doing some terrain analyses and I need to find distance from certain points to mountain ridges. I have used geodata to access SRTM data, so I have a DEM. terra has great built-in methods for calculating slope and TRI.
aspect <- terra::terrain(dem, v = "aspect")
tri <- terra::terrain(dem, v = "TRI")
slope <- terra::terrain(dem, v = "slope")

But, I have found no method for extracting ridges. I thought an approach would be to find the change in slope, but 1) here both peaks and valleys have 0 slope (i.e. there are no negative slopes), and 2) a focal approach returns local maxima whereas I need to find the highest ridge.
Other answers on the stacks have focused on finding the highest point, but I need lines, not point values. In addition, I am using a wide geographic extent, so setting a threshold elevation for ridges is not viable.
Can anyone with more geography experience suggest a solution?
Thanks!


Sounds like you might be interested in the topographic position index (TPI), which you can calculate using terra::terrain(..., v = "TPI"), as a starting point.

@G-Man shown {whitebox} solution, however there is no need to fall outside of {terra}. We can calculate slope and TPI directly, using either terrain() either focal() functions:
r <- geodata::elevation_3s(15, 47, path = "data")
r <- terra::crop(r, terra::ext(15, 15.2, 47.2, 47.4))
terra::plot(r)



s <- terra::terrain(r, v = c("slope", "aspect", "TPI"), unit = "radians")
hillshade <- terra::shade(slope = s$slope, aspect = s$aspect)
terra::plot(hillshade, col =gray(0:50/50), legend = FALSE)


terra::plot(s$slope)



bl <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "white"))(30)
rd <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("white", "darkred"))(30)
pal <- c(bl, rd)

terra::plot(s$TPI, col = pal)


TPI (Topographic Position Index) is defined as difference between the elevation of each cell to the mean elevation of a specified neighborhood around that cell. More neighbourghs will be taken, the bigger difference between tops and valleys.  We can use focal() function to calculate the TPI. Please note positive values means the cell value is higher than average of their neighbours - indicating ridge areas, whitle negative values indicates valleys. See https://www.jennessent.com/downloads/TPI-poster-TNC_18x22.pdf

TPI45 <- terra::focal(r, w=45, fun=\(x) x[1013] - mean(x[-1013]))
terra::plot(TPI45, col = pal)


Now we can clamp TPI to the upper range of values. As the slope is around 0 for ridges and valleys, we can clamp it for lower range of values. In the example below it's sd and first quantile, however you can use your values based on experience.

TPI45_sd <- sd(terra::values(TPI45, na.rm = TRUE))
tpic <- terra::clamp(TPI45, lower = TPI45_sd, values = FALSE)

terra::plot(tpic, col = rd)


The final raster is calculated as multiplication of clipped TPI and slope raster (using fact that NA * x = NA).

q <- quantile(terra::values(s$slope), na.rm = TRUE)[[2]]
slc <- terra::clamp(s$slope, upper = q, values = FALSE)

terra::plot(hillshade, col =gray(0:50/50), legend = FALSE)
(tpic * slc) |>
  terra::plot(col = rd, add = TRUE)


Created on 2024-12-17 with reprex v2.1.1.9000

Thanks to this I was able to create the following code. The simple idea is, to flip the map so that ridges become valleys and then fill it with simulated water and let the water sink down. Then the places with the highest flow accumulation are most likely original ridges (or valleys because we flipped it), whereas low flow accumlation occurs in riverbeds. The function below will find rivers or ridgelines and return and plot them. You can then proceed with using this info to find the distance to your desired point.
How to use the function
Increase the threshold_percentile to make the ridges thicker and less granular. simplifyTol=800 means the distance btw polygons or lines which will be simplified by this distance. This should solve your question.
library(terra)
library(geodata)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(elevatr)
library(whitebox)

get_ridges_or_rivers_from_dem = function(
    dem=0, # give the upside dim, it will be flipped
    ridge_threshold = NULL, # make threshold optional
    ridge_color = "red", # ridges are red
    ridge_lines_width = 2,
    write_ridge_lines = FALSE,
    simplifyTol = 200, # simplify tolerance in meters
    usePolygons = TRUE,
    getRidges = TRUE,
    pos_n_e = c(-105, 40), # position of the dem if no dem is provided in north latitude and east longitude (° deg)
    max_breach_channel_length = Inf,
    max_breach_depth = Inf,
    threshold_method = "percentile", # new parameter to choose threshold method
    threshold_percentile = 0.95, # default percentile for threshold
    plot_threshold_diagnostics = TRUE # new parameter to visualize threshold selection
) {
  # set the current script's location as working directory
  setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
  
  # Check current working directory
  wd <- getwd()
  
  output_dir <- wd # Directory to save outputs
  corrected_dem_path <- file.path(output_dir, "corrected_dem.tif")
  
  dem_path <- file.path(output_dir, "dem.tif")
  flow_direction_path <- file.path(output_dir, "flow_direction.tif")
  flow_accumulation_path <- file.path(output_dir, "flow_accumulation.tif")
  ridge_output_path <- file.path(output_dir, "ridge_lines.tif")
  
  if(dem != 0){
    print("using provided dem!")
  }else{
    print("Fetching a predefined dem!")
    locations <- st_point(pos_n_e) %>%
      st_sfc(crs = 4326)  # WGS 84 coordinate system
    
    # Fetch elevation raster using `elevatr`
    dem <- get_elev_raster(locations = locations, z = 10, src = "aws")  # Ensure you have internet access for this step
    dem <- rast(dem)
  }
  
  print(paste0("Min elevation value: ", min(values(dem)), " m."))
  print(paste0("Max elevation value: ", max(values(dem)), " m."))
  
  if(getRidges == TRUE & min(values(dem)) >= 0){ # only flip if min is more than 0
    dem <- dem * -1
    print("Flipping dem for figuring out the ridges.")
  }
  else{
    print("Keeping dem unflipped.")
  }
  
  print(paste0("Flipped Min elevation value: ", min(values(dem)), " m."))
  print(paste0("Flipped Max elevation value: ", max(values(dem)), " m."))
  plot(dem)
  
  writeRaster(dem, dem_path, overwrite = TRUE)
  
  # Step 2: Hydrological Correction of DEM (Depression Breaching)
  whitebox::wbt_breach_depressions(dem_path, corrected_dem_path, 
                                   max_length = max_breach_channel_length, 
                                   max_depth = max_breach_depth)
  
  # Step 3: Calculate Flow Direction
  whitebox::wbt_d8_pointer(corrected_dem_path, flow_direction_path)
  
  # Step 4: Calculate Flow Accumulation
  whitebox::wbt_d8_flow_accumulation(corrected_dem_path, flow_accumulation_path)
  
  # Step 5: Identify Ridges
  # Load the flow accumulation raster
  flow_accum <- rast(flow_accumulation_path)
  
  # Detailed flow accumulation diagnostics
  flow_accum_values <- terra::values(flow_accum, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  # Print detailed flow accumulation statistics
  print(paste0("Max Flow Accum: ", max(flow_accum_values)))
  print(paste0("Min Flow Accum: ", min(flow_accum_values)))
  print(paste0("Mean Flow Accum: ", mean(flow_accum_values)))
  
  # Threshold selection methods
  if(is.null(ridge_threshold)) {
    if(threshold_method == "percentile") {
      # Use percentile-based threshold
      ridge_threshold <- quantile(flow_accum_values, threshold_percentile)
      print(paste0("Threshold set to ", threshold_percentile * 100, 
                   "th percentile: ", ridge_threshold))
    }else if(threshold_method == "mean") {
      # Mean-based threshold
      ridge_threshold <- mean(flow_accum_values)
      print(paste0("Threshold set to mean: ", ridge_threshold))
    }else{
      stop("Invalid threshold method. Choose 'percentile', 'mean'.")
    }
  }
  
  # Optional diagnostic plotting
  if(plot_threshold_diagnostics) {
    # Histogram of flow accumulation with threshold
    hist(flow_accum_values, 
         breaks = 100, 
         main = "Flow Accumulation Distribution",
         xlab = "Flow Accumulation",
         col = "lightblue")
    abline(v = ridge_threshold, col = "red", lwd = 2, lty = 2)
    legend("topright", 
           legend = paste("Threshold =", round(ridge_threshold, 2)), 
           col = "red", 
           lty = 2)
  }
  
  # Apply threshold to define ridges
  ridges <- flow_accum < ridge_threshold
  
  ridge_lines_sf <- ""
  if (usePolygons) {
    # Convert raster ridges to polygons and simplify geometry
    ridge_polygons <- terra::as.polygons(ridges, dissolve = TRUE)
    ridge_polygons <- terra::simplifyGeom(ridge_polygons, tolerance = simplifyTol)
    
    # Convert polygons to contour lines
    ridge_lines <- terra::as.contour(ridges, levels = 1)
    ridge_lines_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(ridge_lines)
    
  } else {
    # Convert logical raster ridges to contour lines
    ridge_lines <- terra::as.contour(ridges, levels = 1)
    ridge_lines_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(ridge_lines)
    
    # Simplify and smooth ridge lines
    ridge_lines_sf <- sf::st_simplify(ridge_lines_sf, dTolerance = simplifyTol)
    ridge_lines_sf <- sf::st_union(ridge_lines_sf)
  }
  
  if(write_ridge_lines){
    # save ridge lines
    vect_ridge_output_path <- file.path(output_dir, "ridge_lines.shp")
    writeVector(ridge_lines, vect_ridge_output_path, overwrite = TRUE)
    
    # Save the ridge raster
    writeRaster(ridges, ridge_output_path, overwrite = TRUE)
  }
  
  # Plot the DEM and ridge lines using tmap
  tmap_mode("view")  # Set tmap mode to interactive view
  
  # Define breaks for slicing DEM heights
  breaks <- seq(min(values(dem), na.rm = TRUE), max(values(dem), na.rm = TRUE), length.out = 30)
  
  tm <- tm_shape(dem) +
    tm_raster(
      alpha = 0.6,
      style = "fixed",
      breaks = breaks,
      palette = terrain.colors(length(breaks) - 1),
      title = "Elevation (m)"
    ) +
    tm_shape(ridge_lines_sf) +
    tm_lines(
      col = ridge_color,
      lwd = ridge_lines_width,
      title.col = "Ridges"
    ) +
    tm_layout(
      main.title = "Refined Mountain Ridges",
      legend.outside = TRUE
    )
  print(tm)
  
  # Return additional information
  return(list(
    ridge_threshold = ridge_threshold,
    ridge_lines = ridge_lines_sf,
    flow_accumulation_stats = list(
      max = max(flow_accum_values),
      min = min(flow_accum_values),
      mean = mean(flow_accum_values),
      median = median(flow_accum_values)
    )
  ))
}

# Use function to get ridges using 99th percentile
ridges <- get_ridges_or_rivers_from_dem(
  dem=0, # give the upside dim, it will be flipped
  ridge_threshold = NULL, # make threshold optional
  ridge_color = "red", # ridges are red
  ridge_lines_width = 2,
  write_ridge_lines = FALSE,
  simplifyTol = 200, # simplify tolerance in meters
  usePolygons = TRUE,
  getRidges = TRUE,
  pos_n_e = c(13.24,52.3), # position of the dem if no dem is provided in north latitude and east longitude (° deg)
  max_breach_channel_length = Inf, # when flooding some pools will get breached in order to create better flows (like digging wholes in a water damm) # gives the max breach length
  max_breach_depth = Inf, # max breach depth
  plot_threshold_diagnostics = TRUE, # new parameter to visualize threshold selection
  threshold_method = "percentile", # choose threshold method
  threshold_percentile = 0.99 # default percentile for threshold
)

# Use function to get rivers using 99th percentile
rivers <- get_ridges_or_rivers_from_dem(
  dem=0, # give the upside dim, it will be flipped
  ridge_threshold = NULL, # make threshold optional
  ridge_color = "blue", # ridges are red
  ridge_lines_width = 2,
  write_ridge_lines = FALSE,
  simplifyTol = 200, # simplify tolerance in meters
  usePolygons = TRUE,
  getRidges = FALSE,
  pos_n_e = c(13.24,52.3), # position of the dem if no dem is provided in north latitude and east longitude (° deg)
  max_breach_channel_length = Inf, # when flooding some pools will get breached in order to create better flows (like digging wholes in a water damm) # gives the max breach length
  max_breach_depth = Inf, # max breach depth
  plot_threshold_diagnostics = TRUE, # new parameter to visualize threshold selection
  threshold_method = "percentile", # choose threshold method
  threshold_percentile = 0.99 # default percentile for threshold
)

See this example that shows the output of the function for Berlin.

